# Link Outlook contact card to SharePoint 2010 MySite

Tags: my-site, outlook, contacts, registry

In Outlook 2010, when a user hovers over a person's name, a "contact card" pops up with various info such as picture, position, presence, etc. Example:

[image]

As you can see, the contact name is also hyperlinked. This should be pointing to our SharePoint MySite, but when clicking on the name, it points to an incorrect link (our development environment, actually).

I can easily fix this on my local machine by updating the registry key in

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Server Links\Published

in here there is a registry subfolder called "Profile Site" (others may instead have a folder called "MySite") and a key called "Url", where I can set it to the correct MySite 
(e.g. "http://servername/person.aspx?user=")

Referenced from: http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/01/19/if-you-want-to-modify-the-mysite-url-to-point-to-a-new-url-or-mysite-url-is-showing-wrong-in-office-application-eg-outlook.aspx

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dcc37911-524a-4810-a67a-d51289e2af59/outlook-contact-card-name-link-goes-to-wrong-sharepoint-mysite-url?forum=sharepointadminprevious

This will allow any name to link to their correct MySite, but only on my machine.

The problem is, we have many users that this modification needs to be pushed out to. How do we apply this change to all users on the network? More importantly, instead of applying a registry band-aid to each user, how is this link set up initially for all users so that I may reproduce that configuration? Is there somewhere in SP Central Admin/Outlook that it can be set, or is it setup during installation (either of SharePoint or Outlook/Exchange)?

EDIT: Group Policy update is duly noted, but our only real way out of this at this point is to find out how this is originally set via installation or configuration of SharePoint or Outlook. This should be OOTB functionality (pending admin configuration of course) since it obviously seems like a feature supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Have you found any other option Alex? I can't seem to find "Server Links" or "Portal" under the "Common" path in Registry. This is a Windows 8.1 and Outlook 2013. I'm trying to update a link to SharePoint 2013 on-prem User Profile. When checking with Process Monitor while clicking the "Contact Card" it points to a registry key "UseRWHlinkNavigation" under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Internet. Tried updating that to the correct URL but it gets overwritten next time I click the Contact Card SharePoint link. Any suggestion how can I fix the link? Thanks!

Comment: No. Please make a new question. Yours is for a different version of Outlook.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx) to push this registry setting to all users in your environment.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that is not a valid workaround in the eyes of the network management here. What I actually need to know is how this is set up during an install of SharePoint/Outlook, and as such how to reproduce this setup via configuration options instead of what could be seen as "registry hacks" (but not by me!)

Comment: I agree that a registry change is not a solution - unreasonable workaround for something that should clearly have a simple configuration decision and associated experience to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

Go to your SharePoint site.

Click on the desired contact list.

Click on the List tab.

Click Open in Outlook.

Click OK.

Hope This Works,

Peter